# Change of variables in Double integral - explanation of solved example.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm exercising double integrals and here's an solved example that I'm not understand something.

> Calculate $\iint_D xy(x^2 + y^2) dx\,dy$ where $D$ in the first quadrant bounded by:
>
> $1 \le xy \le 2$ and $5 \le x^2 - y^2 \le 9.$

Here's the solution:

> Let $u = xy$ and $v = x^2 - y^2$.
>
> $1 \le u \le 2$ and $5 \le v \le 9$.
>
> Calculate the Jacobian. $$
>         \begin{vmatrix}
>         u'_x & u'_y \\
>         v'_x & v'_y \\
>         \end{vmatrix} = 
>         \begin{vmatrix}
>         y & x \\
>         2x & -2y \\
>         \end{vmatrix}  =  -2y^2 - 2x^2 = -2(x^2 + y^2).$$
>
> $J = \frac{1}{-2(x^2 + y^2)}$ so need to plug $dx\, dy = -\frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}du\,dv$.
>
> $$\iint_D xy(x^2 + y^2)dx\,dy = -\int^9_5\int^2_1 u(x^2 + y^2) \frac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)} = \color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}\int^9_5\int^2_1udu\,dv} = -\frac{1}{2}\int^9_5\bigg(\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg|^2_1\bigg)dv = -\frac{1}{2}\int^9_5(2-\frac{1}{2})dv = -\frac{3}{4}\bigg(v\bigg|^9_5\bigg) = -3.$$

## My question:

In the part I marked in $\text{$\color{red}{red}$}$, how has $(x^2 + y^2)$ just gone away?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was cancelled. There is an $x^2+y^2$ in the numerator and in the denominator.

Comment: I should take a break .. thanks